# How to manipulate first 3 entries in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am currently working on a project where i am pulling out data using
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($the_data))

i want to make the first, say 3-4 results a different background color and then leave the rest as already styled, i am sure there is some simple option here but i just don't know where to look really...

Hope you can help, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like:

```
#specialResult {background-color: #fff; }
#normalResult {background-color: #000; }
```

So when you are looping through your while statement, you will want to keep track of what result number you are on:

```
$i = 0;
while (...)
{
    if ($i < 4) echo "<div class='specialResult'>";
    else echo "<div class='normalResult'>"; 

    .... rest of your code

    $i++;
}
```

for shorter looking code you could do:

```
$i = 0;
while (...)
{
    ?><div class='<?php echo ($i++ < 4 ?"specialResult":"normalResult); ?>'><?php

    .... rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
$i = 0;
$r = mysql_fetch_array($the_data);
foreach($r as $row) {
    if($i <= 4) {
        // Do special styling...
    } else {
        // Do normal styling.
    }
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Haha, yep, I was editing it as you said that, I guess. Got in too much of a hurry.

Comment: Hi, it does the styling right but unless i'm missing something it isn't cyclying through the data in the array just giving me the same one again and again

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like :

```
$i = 0;
while ( ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $result ) ) && $i < 4 ) {
    /* Your first 4 rows */
    echo 'Special : ' . $row['title'];
    ++$i;   // Don't forget to increment
} while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc () ) {
    /* Normal way */
    echo $row['title'] . ' is already outdated';
}
```

And prefer mysql_fetch_assoc() instead of mysql_fetch_array() ;)

Comment: thanks for the input, will use mysql_fetch_assoc - seems to make more sense